# What is the difference between a 'delving' and a 'kenning'?

Tags: the-unhewn-throne

In *[The Emperor's Blades](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17910124-the-emperor-s-blades)*, magic-users called leaches are able to draw from a 'well' to perform magic. Most of the time, this is called 'kenning', as in:

> A leach's kenning is a dangerous  thing.

Sometimes however, magic is referred to as a 'delving', as in:

> A week later, I had my first delving.

I have only read the first book, and I cannot ascertain the difference between the two. Is there one, and if so, what is it?

Comment: As far as I can tell from a glance at the three novels, delving simply means going *into* your well (typically when young and inexperienced) whereas "kenning" or "dipping" involves drawing power out of the well and using it to affect a change.

Comment: Notably, the term delving is only used twice in all three books; Once to describe the character's first occurence of magic, the second time when Valyn asks "*“Kaden,” Valyn gestured, “you’re with me on the bird. It’s the safest place for now, especially if Yurl doubles back. Talal, can you delve yet?”*". Those are literally the only occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kenning` is derived from `Ken`: a noun meaning `range of knowledge`.  Thus, the use of `Kenning` in the book suggests, `use of the knowledge`.  Further, the suggestion is that the mage has a mystic type knowledge that gives him/her a special ability.

It makes sense then, that the related term, `delving` (a verb, meaning `to reach into`) is rarely used in the book (as noted in the comments) because mages took great pains to keep their ability a secret. This also limited the author's ability to use the term since few people in the UhT-verse had ever seen or detected an actual delving.